# How can I map two elements of a tuple to each other using a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a tuple that has the two elements

```
(a, b)
```

How can I create a dictionary that maps the first element to the second so it looks like

```
{a : b}
```

I have tried

```
new_dict = {tup[0]:tup[1]}
```

but I receive a

> TypeError: unhashable type 'list'

Comment: `{tup[0]:tup[1]}` may be.

Comment: I have tried new_dict = {tup[0]:tup[1]} but I receive a "TypeError: unhashable type 'list'"

Comment: May be your `a` is a list, which can't be a dictionary key. Dictionary keys need to be immutable, but lists are mutable.

Comment: `new_dict = {tup[0]:tup[1]}` should work. How have you defined the tuple?

Comment: Show your (a, b) differences in mutability will change the responses you get.

Comment: @H.Rath next time please provide your attempted code in your question. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Please update your answer to show an actual example of your tuple values. What are `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving means your key `a` is a list, which can't be used as a key. Something like this

```
(['item'], 'value')
```

When what you probably want is

```
('key', 'value')
```

Typically, dictionary keys are strings, though not strictly so. They can also be integers or other immutable types. "Immutable" means it can't be updated in place. A list can be updated in place by adding or removing an item, so it can't be properly hashed and, subsequently, can't be used as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that the first item of your tuple is a list. Lists are mutable and therefore can't be dictionary keys, but tuples can. So, convert the would-be key from list to tuple:

```
new_dict = { tuple(tup[0]), tup[1] }
```